# Match a line and cat multiple files into one file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cat

I have a file with 3 columns and 4426 row some thing like this

file1 :

```
DAEQUEG00000025 FP3SLUG00002140 FOMPING00001058 
DAEQUEG00001923 FP3SLUG00002391 FOMPING00000186 
DAEQUEG00000047 FP3SLUG00002116 FOMPING00001081 
DAEQUEG00000321 FP3SLUG00006281 FOMPING00000374
```

and I have same number of files and named in same way (`DAEQUEG00000025.fa  FP3SLUG00002140.fa  FOMPING00001058.fa`)

I would like to match the first line to a list of files and `cat` them into one file.

expected output(first line in one file)

```
>DAEQUEG00000025  
ATGTTGTTTAGATTGGCCCGGCGAGCTACAAGCCCGCTCACCCGCTCGATGGCGACGCAT
GCGCGAGGACTCCCTGCTCTACTCGAGAAGAAACCAGACGATGTAGTCATAACATTCGCA
>FP3SLUG00002140
AAGCGTACTGCTATGGCACGCGCGAGGAAGGGTCAGCTAAAGGACATCCCTGTCGACGAG
>FOMPING00001058 
CTTATGCAGGCTCTCATCAAGACTCAGCTCGATCCAGCTATGCTAGAGGACATATGCGTA
GGGACTTGTCACCCTCCGTCACCGACGTACATCTCTCGAGCAGCTGCTCTTGCTGCTGGA
```

Comment: *4426 row* and *i have same number of files* means 4426 files?

Comment: ..and what did you try for yourself and where did you fail?

Comment: Just the first line? Then you want to cat a total of 3 files?

Comment: Also, show some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes every row has 3 files put into one file

Comment: @jas  i havent tired but i did for few line which is time consuming, just sought of help

Comment: @JamesBrown question edited

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
while read -r a b c; do 
    cat "$a.fa" "$b.fa" "$c.fa" > "${a}_${b}_${c}.fa"; 
done < file1
```

you get several files with compound name as output, for example

> DAEQUEG00000025_FP3SLUG00002140_FOMPING00001058.fa

```
>DAEQUEG00000025  
ATGTTGTTTAGATTGGCCCGGCGAGCTACAAGCCCGCTCACCCGCTCGATGGCGACGCAT
GCGCGAGGACTCCCTGCTCTACTCGAGAAGAAACCAGACGATGTAGTCATAACATTCGCA
>FP3SLUG00002140
AAGCGTACTGCTATGGCACGCGCGAGGAAGGGTCAGCTAAAGGACATCCCTGTCGACGAG
>FOMPING00001058 
CTTATGCAGGCTCTCATCAAGACTCAGCTCGATCCAGCTATGCTAGAGGACATATGCGTA
GGGACTTGTCACCCTCCGTCACCGACGTACATCTCTCGAGCAGCTGCTCTTGCTGCTGGA
```